# What is the difference between Related To Id and Related Record Id while creating Tasks in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am creating a task in the flow and there are three fields that i needed some clarification on

Related Record ID

Related To ID (this i think is whatid)

Name ID

What are they used for

[image]

Comment: Related to Id is What id and Name Id is Who Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NameId` is WhoId field on Task object.

`Related To Id` is WhatId field on Task Object as per the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)

> The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

`Related Record Id`  is special field for some object specific actions as per [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_quick.htm&type=5)

> Only for object-specific actions. The ID of the record from which the
> action executes.
>
> For example, the action creates a case that’s associated with a given
> account. Assign the ID for that account to Related Record ID.
>
> This parameter accepts single-value resources of any type. That value
> is treated as text.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the actual text from the article for Related Record Id